# Why can't I insert more than one table into one database in SQLiteDatabase browser

Tags: android, database, sqlite, store

I can't seem to insert multiple tables into one database. Plus, I've followed this example [Multiple Table SQLite DB Adapter(s) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063510/multiple-table-sqlite-db-adapters-in-android).

I am not sure on what to code in the Cars.java, Cycles.java and Boats.java classes. I am also not sure on which DBAdapter to declare in those 3 classes. I've managed to create database for 3 tables. But no tables are created.

This is CarsDBAdapter class and is similar to BoatsDBAdapter and CyclesDBAdapter classes.

```
public class CarsDBAdapter
{
    public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String MODEL = "model";
    public static final String YEAR = "year";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "cars";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);          
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {           
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {           
        }
    }// end DatabaseHelper class

    public CarsDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public CarsDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
        this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        this.mDbHelper.close();
    }

    /*public long insertCars(String name, String model, String year)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(MODEL, model);
        initialValues.put(YEAR, year);
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }*/

    public long create(String name, String model, String year)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        initialValues.put(NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(MODEL, model);
        initialValues.put(YEAR, year);
        return this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); 
    }

    public boolean deleteCar(long rowId) 
    {          
        return this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; //$NON-NLS-1$     
    }

     public Cursor getAllCars() 
     {          
         return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { ROW_ID, NAME, MODEL, YEAR }, null, null, null, null, null);       
     }

     public Cursor getCar(long rowId) throws SQLException
     {
         Cursor mCursor = this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ROW_ID, NAME, MODEL, YEAR}, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId,
                 null, null, null, null, null);

         if(mCursor != null)
         {
             mCursor.moveToFirst();
         }

         return mCursor;
     }

     public boolean updateCar(long rowId, String name, String model, String year)
     {
         ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

         args.put(NAME, name);
         args.put(MODEL, model);
         args.put(YEAR, year);
         return this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, ROW_ID + "=" + rowId, null) >0;  
     }

}//end CarsDBAdapter class
```

This is the DBAdapter where I create the 3 tables:

```
public class DBAdapter
{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stuffIOwn";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CARS = "create table cars(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //$NON-NLS-1$
            +CarsDBAdapter.NAME+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
            +CarsDBAdapter.MODEL+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
            +CarsDBAdapter.YEAR+ " TEXT" +");"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BOATS = "create table boats(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //$NON-NLS-1$
            +BoatsDBAdapter.NAME+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
            +BoatsDBAdapter.MODEL+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
            +BoatsDBAdapter.YEAR+ " TEXT" +");"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CYCLES = "create table cycles(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //$NON-NLS-1$
            +CyclesDBAdapter.NAME+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
            +CyclesDBAdapter.MODEL+ " TEXT," //$NON-NLS-1$
            +CyclesDBAdapter.YEAR+ " TEXT" +");"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)     
    {         
        this.context = ctx;         
        this.DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);     
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper      
    {         
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)          
        {             
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);         
            }          
        @Override         
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)          
        {             
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CARS);             
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BOATS);             
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CYCLES);                   
        }          
        @Override         
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)          
        {                            
            // Adding any table mods to this guy here         
        }     
    }//end DatabaseHelper class

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException      
    {         
    this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();         
    return this;     
    }      
    /**      
     * close the db 
     *return type: void      
     */    
    public void close()      
    {        
        this.DBHelper.close();     
    }
```

THis is Cars.java class and it's similar to Cycles.java & Boats.java classes.

```
public class Cars extends Activity
{
    final Context context = this;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cars);

        CarsDBAdapter carsDB = new CarsDBAdapter(this);

        //DBAdapter dbA = new DBAdapter(this);

        /*carsDB.open();
        long id;
        id = carsDB.insertCars("Mercedes", "MERCDS", "2000");
        id = carsDB.insertCars("BMW", "BMWTO", "1999");
        carsDB.close();*/

        carsDB.open();

        Cursor c = carsDB.getAllCars();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                DisplayContact(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        carsDB.close();

        Button btnMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(context, VehiclesMenu.class);
                    startActivity(menuIntent);

                }
            });
    }//end onCreate()

    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
    {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Name: " + c.getString(1)
                        + "\n" + "Model:  " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Year: " + c.getString(3),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

I really need help with this. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've added in the codes but you can look at the link above. It links to the example which I followed.

Comment: Its possible to create multiple table in one database. What you want to know in that? And Can you please show your DBAdapter code.So that we can judge the flaw

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple table in one dbHelper then do like this in the onCreate method.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Abc(_id INTEGER ,Category text ,Category_Name,Date text);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Xyz(_id INTEGER ,Name text not null);");
    }
```

You can write any number of db.execSql() to create the table.

Comment: If still you not getting it then let me know. I will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String sqlTable1 = "CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,NAME TEXT);";
    private static String sqlTable2 = "CREATE TABLE TEST2 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,NAME TEXT);";
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "MYDB", null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.execSQL(sqlTable1);
        db.execSQL(sqlTable2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void initialInsert() {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST(NAME) VALUES('YOUR NAME')";
        String sql2 = "INSERT INTO TEST2(NAME) VALUES('YOUR NAME')";
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql2);
    }
}
```

CREATE THE OBJECT OF THE HELPER CLASS FROM YOUR ACTIVITY LIKE:

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
//FOR INSERTING INITIAL VALUES      
helper.initialInsert();
```