# Records are not inserting into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two table in an Sqlite database. The columns of the first table are `_id` as `primary key`, `note` `date`and `_cid` as `foreign key` . The columns of the second table are `_cid` as `primary key`, `Category`.

Some default records, I have inserted into second table at the time of creating it.

Both Tables are created successfully. **but when I am inserting record into first table not inserting**. not getting any type of exception. Please guide me.

`Table 1`

`private static final String DB__CREATE1 =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_CATE + 
            "(_cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            "Category TEXT not null);";`

`Table 2`

`private static final String DB__CREATE2 =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            "Note TEXT not null, "+
            "NoteDateTime TEXT not null, " +
            "_cid INTEGER not null, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(_cid) REFERENCES Categories(_cid));";`

Method for inserting data

`public` `void` `insertData1( long c_id, String discription, String nDate)` {

```
    ContentValues  contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("note", discription);
    contentValues.put("date", nDate);
    contentValues.put("_cid", c_id);
    open();
    database.insert("TABLE_NAME", null,contentValues);
    close();
}`
```

calling statement

`dbConnector.insertData1(1, textview.getText().toString(), nDateTime.toString());`

Comment: You will need to post your code. It is impossible to debug your problem with what you have provided.

Comment: So, What you have try ??

Comment: you can print that exception by using Log.i("tag", e);

Comment: I have put some code @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really hard to point to the exact problem without the complete code. I can see the answers posted before quite logical.
However, from my experience of working with multiple table database, things are quite tedious and do not work in the way we do with a single table only.

I had a similar problem, I once created a multi-table database and I still don't way what's the problem because it created the tables, but it could not insert. 
Later I followed this procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899110/1351867 
it worked!

So my guess is, you might have problem with database adapter or helper classes, and maybe it's confusing between two tables. 
Please post your full code if you still face problems.

Answer (score 0):

For the first table It should look like this:

```
    private static final String DB__CREATE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_CATE + "( "+_cid+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Category +"TEXT not null);";
```

but it´s hard to know it really without seeing the complete code. Have You declared variables for "Category" (is it a String)?

And for Your second the same, have Your declared variables for "_id", "Note", "NoteDateTime" etc?

### EDIT

ok, I see something I don´t understand. As You described above, the first table consists of id, note date and foreign key. But this should be anything like this:

```
    private static final String DB__CREATE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_CATE + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ "date TEXT not null,"+ " Category TEXT not null);";
```

You passed _cid instead of _id to the first column and You forgot the Date Column.

Then, in your second table, you Reference "Categories(_cid)", but shouldn´t it be "Category(_cid)" like declared in Your first Table?

Comment: No, I put column names directly & Category is String @Opiatefuchs