# Busy timeout for SQLite on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to increase the busy timeout for the SQLite on Android ?
It would be useful for situations when two threads are simultaneously trying  to insert some data to DB and exception is thrown:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 5: database is locked.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have one instance of SQLiteOpenHelper then it works.

[The answer which explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-is-best-practice-with-sqlite-and-android/3689883#3689883)