# When should I close the DatabaseHelper?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113244/busy-timeout-for-sqlite-on-android) link, when is a good time to close the connection if you only have one connection? I have a service running in the background at all times. When is a good time to call the `close()` function? Any suggestions?

Comment: check this and read carefully................

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-is-best-practice-with-sqlite-and-android/3689883#3689883

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not actually have to call `close()`. For example, if you implement a content provider, there is no opportunity to call `close()`. We have been told that, due to the way SQLite is implemented, not calling `close()` will not cause any particular problem.

That being said, you really should reconsider having "a service running in the background too all the time".