# why to close Database connection

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Why should we close a database connection?
what can happen if a connection is left open?
does the connection gets closed automatically when app exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really necessary to close your database connection. See this [question on stackoverflow for a more detailed explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414049/android-when-to-close-the-databasehelper)

Answer (score 1):

1) Open connections as late as possible

2) Close connections as soon as possible

The connection itself is returned to the connection pool. Connections are a limited resource. Any new connection you establish that has exactly the same connection string will be able to reuse the connection from the pool.

Answer (score 0):

To release the resourcess like handler,we should use  DBHelper.close(); to close Database, if you not close database,its may arise problem when you try to reconnect to Database.
  So to overcome this problem , we must close Database.