# Never close Android SQLite connection

Tags: android

What happens if you simply never close your connection?  I know you get exceptions if you don't close it and try to open another one, but what happens if you have a global singleton, and you simply don't close it?  Any idea?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A rift is formed in the space-time continuum, threatening extinction of all life in the universe, until the day is saved by a bunch of humans in brightly-colored funny-looking outfits (including some with *capes*, if you can believe it).

Oh, no, wait. That was just a comic book.

---

Actually, nothing much happens. I have been told, by Googlers and other Android experts, that due to the way SQLite works (particularly its handling of transactions), nothing bad should happen if you fail to close the database.

In fact, if you implement a content provider, you will have this same effect, as content providers are not called with any sort of `onDestroy()` method, meaning you will never have an opportunity to close your database. A content provider will just live until the process is terminated. Personally, this really bugs me, which is one of the reasons I try to minimize my use of content providers.

Comment: Content providers are one of the least understood and most overused parts of Android. They're heavily pushed in the docs, or at least the early docs, but they should only be used if you plan to share data with 3rd party apps. I've seen people use them just to serialize DB access, which is terrible.  Anyway, I figured having one static connection would be fine. I did a lot of work testing what happens with multiple connections. Summary, its bad: http://www.touchlab.co/blog/android-sqlite-locking/.  Working on a rehash of connection management for ORMLite. Thanks.

Comment: That's a great blog post, BTW.

Comment: That blog post no longer seems to exist. New link?

Comment: @John Also here... I think they are identical though http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474398246/android-sqlite-locking

Comment: @KevinGalligan that is so true, using just one static database connection works great !

Comment: @John Both posts are me, at different times.

Comment: @KevinGalligan what about memory? I know little about SQLite memory management, but I wonder - if I'll have an always open connection, won't it consume memory somehow? Or is memory consumed only by Cursors and released when I close them - and no other places to worry about? DB layout maybe, info, tables, some metadata, no?

Comment: @dimsuz: "if I'll have an always open connection, won't it consume memory somehow?" -- not much. "Or is memory consumed only by Cursors and released when I close them" -- generally speaking, yes.

Comment: @dimsuz Agree with CommonsWare. I don't have a lot of hard data, but have debugged many apps for memory issues. Was doing that today, in fact. That's never been an issue. In general, memory problems == Bitmap. However, SQLITE is implemented in C code, so memory alloc may not be very visible. Interesting topic to look into.

Comment: Yes, I suspected so, thank you all! I will go on with this solution and in case I run into some memory issues (hopefully not), will investigate.

Comment: Looks likek Alex's post moved again

http://kagii-blog.tumblr.com/post/6828016869/android-sqlite-locking