# Writing to database within a Service

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service

In my Android app, the user can receive notifications than contain a serial number that I want to store in my SQLite database. However, I saw that it may be unsafe to write in the database within the `Service`, as it can compete with others instances of it in the current `Activity`.

Is it really unsafe to write in the database within a `Service`? Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your SQLiteOpenHelper as a singleton.

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static MyDatabaseHelper instance;

    public static MyDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if ( instance == null ){
            instance = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Look into SQLite Write-Ahead Logging

> There are advantages and disadvantages to using WAL instead of a rollback journal. Advantages include:
>
> 1. WAL is significantly faster in most scenarios.
> 2. WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.
> 3. Disk I/O operations tends to be more sequential using WAL.
> 4. WAL uses many fewer fsync() operations and is thus less vulnerable to problems on systems where the fsync() system call is broken.

Source: https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

### Android (API level 11+):

> The best way to enable write-ahead logging is to pass the
>   ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING flag to openDatabase(String,
>   SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int). This is more efficient than
>   calling enableWriteAheadLogging().

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("db_filename", cursorFactory,
    SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY |
    SQLiteDatabase.ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING,
    myDatabaseErrorHandler);

db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
```

Source 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not unsafe if you use the same DB connection instance.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450977/android-sqlite-with-multi-thread)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you exactly mean with "as it can compete with others instances of it" . Just create a service with a method that updates your database and start it (and stop it after the job is done) whenever you need it.