# Failed to open database/ Failed to change locale for (database) to 'en_US'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-juno

I have read solution from [Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/my.easymedi.controller/databases/EasyMediInfo.db' to 'en_US'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491675/failed-to-change-locale-for-db-data-data-my-easymedi-controller-databases-easy) but it doesnt help me. I still have the same error.

These is my `DBHelper` class. Could you look into it and help me?

```
package com.example.mgr;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.mgr/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "Mgr.Test.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    public static final String KEY_DATE = "DataWstawiena";

    public static final String KEY_TRESC = "Tresc";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Mgr.Test";

    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "InformacjeZDziekanatu";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 18;
    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        System.out.println("------Odpalam DBHelpera---wolane z konstruktora----");
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        System.out.println("----Baza istnieje: " + dbExist + "-----");

        if(dbExist){
            System.out.println("----Baza istnieje!");
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            System.out.println("----Baza istnieje! znow");
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }
        dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist){
            System.out.println("----Baza nie istnieje");

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                System.out.println("Bede kopiowal");
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        System.out.println("----Baza istnieje w checkDB!");
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS|SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            System.out.println("Bazka otwarta!");

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            System.out.println("database does't exist yet");

        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            System.out.println("Zamykam baze");

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS|SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        return myDataBase;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" ----Jestem w mtodzie onUpgrade------");
        //DATABASE_VERSION++;

    }

    /**
    * Wykonuje zapytanie SQL
    * @param query - zapytanie SQL
    * @return zwraca Stringa z rezultatem
    */
    public String executeQuery(String query){
    String result = "";
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    String dataWs ="Data Wstawienia ";
    String tresc = "Tresc";
    result = dataWs + tresc + "\n";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
    do
    {
    result +=  cursor.getString(1) +" "+ cursor.getString(3)+"\n";
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return result;
    }

    /**
    * Wykonuje zapytanie SQL i zwraca tablice
    * @param query - zapytanie SQL
    * @return zwraca tablie Stringa z rezultatem
    */
    public ArrayList<String> executeQueryTab(String query){
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    String dataWs ="Data Wstawienia ";
    String tresc = "Tresc";
    result.add(dataWs + tresc);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
    do
    {
    result.add(cursor.getString(1) +" "+ cursor.getString(3));
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return result;
    }


        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

It worked perfectly before but I have made some upgrades of database and then it stopped work. I guess that this is the source of this error but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance!

On your request:

I have call createDataBase method in my **MainActivity** class, as you can see below:

```
package com.example.mgr;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    TextView tv;
    Adapter adapter;
    SQLiteDatabase as;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button infDlaStudButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infDlaStud);
        Button infDlaKandButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infDlaKand);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        infDlaStudButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        infDlaKandButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        infDlaKandButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ble();

            }

        });

        infDlaStudButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ble();
            }
        });

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            System.out.println("Stworzyłam bazę danych");

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("nie moge to create database");

        }
        System.out.println("bede otwierdal baze danych w glowej metodzie");

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }

    void ble() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ble", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Yes, the **android_metadata** table exist in the database and has '*en_US*' value.

I have create new, very simple database **Drzewo.db**. When this table has only 2 tables: **andoid_metadata** and another one (**Przyjeci**) then everything works! But later I have added new table and tried to make an upgrade and I have the same error.

There are my **logs** (from this new database):

```
12-04 19:58:41.959: E/SQLiteLog(2293): (11) database corruption at line 50741 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-04 19:58:41.959: E/SQLiteLog(2293): (11) database corruption at line 50780 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-04 19:58:41.969: E/SQLiteLog(2293): (11) statement aborts at 16: [SELECT locale FROM android_metadata UNION SELECT NULL ORDER BY locale DESC LIMIT 1] 
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.mgr/databases/Drzewo.db'.
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.example.mgr/databases/Drzewo.db' to 'en_US'.
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:386)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:854)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at com.example.mgr.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:53)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at com.example.mgr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForString(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:367)
12-04 19:58:42.056: E/SQLiteDatabase(2293):     ... 28 more
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293): Couldn't open Drzewo.db for writing (will try read-only):
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.example.mgr/databases/Drzewo.db' to 'en_US'.
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:386)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:854)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at com.example.mgr.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:53)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at com.example.mgr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForString(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:367)
12-04 19:58:42.219: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(2293):   ... 28 more
12-04 19:58:42.259: D/AndroidRuntime(2293): Shutting down VM
12-04 19:58:42.280: W/dalvikvm(2293): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mgr/com.example.mgr.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 5 to 6: Drzewo.db
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 5 to 6: Drzewo.db
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:245)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at com.example.mgr.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:53)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at com.example.mgr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293):     ... 11 more
```

I work on *eclipse* *juno* + *Android 4.2.2*

Comment: I am not an expert, but just a thought. Did the upgrade cause a change in the database path by any chance?

Comment: No, no changes. I have just copied new database to the assert folder. Nothing else.

Comment: I need to know where you're calling createDatabase(), please update your code.

Comment: Instead of opening the database as OPEN_READONLY, have you tried OPEN_READWRITE?

Comment: Did you check if the table android_metadata still exists after the upgrade. Also if the table exists, there has to a row in the table with the value en_US in it.

Comment: is it exactly the same error? can you post your logcat please?

Comment: Please try two things: 
1)change OPEN_READONLY to OPEN_READWRITE
2)call getReadableDatabase() in your onUpgrade method before you call copyDatabase...

Comment: If you scroll down to the bottom of the error message stack, there is a line that reads: 12-04 19:58:42.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2293): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 5 to 6: Drzewo.db. Try opening the database in OPEN_READWRITE mode.

Comment: @SaeidFarivar-unfortunately no changes. I have still the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db to 'en\_US'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631316/android-sqliteexception-failed-to-change-locale-for-db-to-en-us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the database file is actually corrupted. 
You can try to open it with [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

Also, you can do some other checks and try to restore it in case it is corrupted, if you install sqlite in your computer. You can follow this steps:

1. Get sqlite [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and install it
2. Open command a add path to sqlite oyour environnment variable path to allow you to launch sqlite commands everywhere
3. Go to the directory, where you have the database, and launch SQLite:

   ```
   sqlite3 yourfile.db
   ```
4. You can check the database integrity by:

   ```
   pragma integrity_check;
   ```
5. If it says that the file is ok, then we are lost!  If it is corrupted, lets try to restore it.

Sometimes the best solution for a corrupted sqlite3 database is simple yet effective: Dump and Restore

1. Export your data  to an sql file:

   ```
   echo .dump | sqlite3.exe yourdbname.db > yourdbname.sql
   ```
2. Change file name mv yourdbname.db yourdbname.db.original
3. Create a new database with your sql.

   ```
   sqlite3.exe -init yourdbname.sql yourdbname.db
   ```
4. Open the new file with sqlite browser, and see what happens!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't put all these codes in the comments, so please try these:
Keep in mind that I am not adding all the boilerplates... ok?

Change checkDb method:

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){
     File dbFile = new File( DATABASE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME );
     return dbFile.exists();
}
```

Change createDb method:

```
public void createDataBase() {
    if(checkDb()){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        copyDatabase();
    }
}
```

Change copyDatabase() method:

```
private void copyDataBase(){
      getReadableDatabase();

      //add the rest of your current implementation

}
```

Change accessibility of your constructor to private and add these methods:

```
private DBHelper mInstance = null;
public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
   if(mInstance == null)
        mInstance = new DBHelper(context)
   return mInstance;
}
//remove the old openDatabase method
public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
   return getReadableDatabase(); //or you can use getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Besides I noticed that your db version in the posted code is 18 while in the logs that you posted it's saying 5 or 6? Can you post the latest logs...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you get is that the file cannot be opened. Probably its something wrong with your path (it could be slightly different between diferent android versions), and anyways, you should never hardcode it.

**You can get database path with `context.getDatabasePath();`  you pass the desired name to the file (no matter if it exists or not). And actually you are supposed to do it that way**

For that, at any place you are using something like  `String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;`
you should change it for

```
 String outFileName =myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath() ;
```

and that's the real valid location for your file. so , your   copyDataBase()  will be like this

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open("db/" + DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName =myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath() ;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

and the same change in your   `private boolean checkDataBase()`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. After all tries I think that problem could be in my database. Anyway, thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```