# android sqlite : Failed to change locale for db to 'zh_CN'

Tags: android, sqlite, corruption

There is a similar problem,

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for
>   db  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException:
>   database disk image is malformed (code 11)

[Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/my.easymedi.controller/databases/EasyMediInfo.db' to 'en_US'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491675/failed-to-change-locale-for-db-data-data-my-easymedi-controller-databases-easy)

But my database is created by android through SQLiteOpenHelper. And it appears in a few of devices.
I want to know what can cause this problem , since I even can not reproduce it.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.android.settings/databases/myDB.db' to 'zh_CN'.
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:386)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:833)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
at com.example.optimizecenter.packages.e.mO(PackagesManager.java:150)
at com.example.optimizecenter.packages.PackageSyncService.onHandleIntent(PackageSyncService.java:24)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForString(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:367)
... 18 more
```

Here is my helper class.

```java
public class PackageDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public PackageDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, PackageColumns.DB_NAME, null, PackageColumns.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("create table ");
        sb.append(PackageColumns.TABLE_PACKAGE);
        sb.append(" (");
        sb.append(PackageColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, ");
        sb.append(PackageColumns.COLUMN_APPLICATION_LABEL + " TEXT ,");
        sb.append(PackageColumns.COLUMN_PACKAGE_NAME + " TEXT ,");
        sb.append(PackageColumns.COLUMN_VERSION_NAME + " TEXT ,");
        sb.append(PackageColumns.COLUMN_VERSION_CODE + " INTEGER ,");
        sb.append(PackageColumns.COLUMN_IC_LAUNCHER + " BOLD");
        sb.append(");");
        db.execSQL(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // ignore
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
SQLiteDatabase db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.android.settings/databases/myDB.db", null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS|SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

Try this code sample to your code..

If you have sqlite browser, open your database..
In your database, locale of android_metadata table seem not be **en_US**

Comment: With my code, lots of devices works normally. But some users report this bug, I can not reproduce it. the locale of android_metadata will change itself when I change the Phone language in android settings, and it works well. I even delete the locale or fill with Meaningless words, APP works well and change it to the current phone language...

Comment: XiaoMi 2s. But there is just several hundreds, ohter millions Xiaomi 2S is OK ...

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db; db.setLocale(Locale.CHINA);   test this code when you create/open your database..

Comment: I have no ideas to solve coz same model-some devices got error..I think this some devices are not allowed to change 'zh_CN;

Comment: thanks ! I will try to build this kind of scenario to test it ! Can you give some ideas ?

Comment: I suspect that your db file is fine..Try this link to reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283580/failed-to-open-database-failed-to-change-locale-for-database-to-en-us?rq=1   I have no ideas to test now..But if I have,I will discuss it..By the way, what is your app does?

Comment: minitor APP changes, like install uninstall, then do some clean works