# Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.scoreup/databases/scoreUp' to 'en_GB'

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I have recently updated one of my application and I get the above error in very rare cases. This error occurs only when the user tries to update the app over the existing one. This doesn't happen every time and on every device. 
I have found a similar issue on [Android SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db to 'en_US'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631316/android-sqliteexception-failed-to-change-locale-for-db-to-en-us) However the replies didn't solve my proble. I have been trying to get a solution for this from over a wee and I have failed. 
I have used SQLiteDatabase and so I am not giving any path to my DataBase.
The crash report is as follows

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.scoreup/databases/scoreUp' to 'en_US'.
0
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration
SQLiteConnection.java:393
1
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open
SQLiteConnection.java:218
2
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open
SQLiteConnection.java:193
3
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked
SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463
4
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open
SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185
5
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open
SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177
6
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner
SQLiteDatabase.java:806
7
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open
SQLiteDatabase.java:791
8
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase
SQLiteDatabase.java:694
9
android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase
ContextImpl.java:1148
10
android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase
ContextWrapper.java:268
11
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked
SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223
12
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase
SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163
13
com.scoreup.gson.DatabaseHandler.openDatabase
DatabaseHandler.java:35
14
com.scoreup.gson.DatabaseHandler.getQuizBots
DatabaseHandler.java:379
15
com.scoreup.activity.earn.fragments.EarnScreenBottomFragmentWinners.onCreateView
EarnScreenBottomFragmentWinners.java:66
16
android.app.Fragment.performCreateView
Fragment.java:2053
17
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
FragmentManager.java:894
18
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
FragmentManager.java:1067
19
android.app.BackStackRecord.run
BackStackRecord.java:834
20
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
FragmentManager.java:1452
21
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions
FragmentManager.java:483
22
android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate
FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167
23
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate
ViewPager.java:1073
24
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate
ViewPager.java:919
25
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure
ViewPager.java:1441
26
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
27
android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal
RelativeLayout.java:727
28
android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure
RelativeLayout.java:463
29
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
30
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins
ViewGroup.java:5535
31
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout
LinearLayout.java:1436
32
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical
LinearLayout.java:722
33
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure
LinearLayout.java:613
34
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
35
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins
ViewGroup.java:5535
36
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout
LinearLayout.java:1436
37
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical
LinearLayout.java:722
38
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure
LinearLayout.java:613
39
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
40
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins
ViewGroup.java:5535
41
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure
FrameLayout.java:436
42
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
43
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
DrawerLayout.java:851
44
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
45
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins
ViewGroup.java:5535
46
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure
FrameLayout.java:436
47
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
48
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins
ViewGroup.java:5535
49
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout
LinearLayout.java:1436
50
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical
LinearLayout.java:722
51
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure
LinearLayout.java:613
52
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
53
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins
ViewGroup.java:5535
54
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure
FrameLayout.java:436
55
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure
PhoneWindow.java:2615
56
android.view.View.measure
View.java:17547
57
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure
ViewRootImpl.java:2015
58
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy
ViewRootImpl.java:1173
59
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals
ViewRootImpl.java:1379
60
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal
ViewRootImpl.java:1061
61
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run
ViewRootImpl.java:5885
62
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run
Choreographer.java:767
63
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks
Choreographer.java:580
64
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame
Choreographer.java:550
65
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run
Choreographer.java:753
66
android.os.Handler.handleCallback
Handler.java:739
67
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
Handler.java:95
68
android.os.Looper.loop
Looper.java:135
69
android.app.ActivityThread.main
ActivityThread.java:5254
70
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
Native Method
71
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
Method.java:372
72
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
ZygoteInit.java:903
73
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
ZygoteInit.java:698
```

My dataBase code is

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static DatabaseHandler instance;
        private SQLiteDatabase dbInstance;
        private int mOpenCounter;

        private DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public static synchronized DatabaseHandler getDBInstance(Context context) {
            if (instance == null) {
                return new DatabaseHandler(context);
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
            mOpenCounter++;
            if (mOpenCounter == 1) {
                // Opening new database
                dbInstance = this.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            return dbInstance;
        }

        public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
            mOpenCounter--;
            if (mOpenCounter == 0) {
                // Closing database
                dbInstance.close();

            }
        }

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scoreUp";
        public static final String TABLE_LEARNARTICLES = "learn_articles";

        public static final String ARTICLE_CODE = "article_code";
        public static final String ARTICLE_SHORT_DESC = "article_short_desc";
        public static final String ARTICLE_DATE = "article_date";
        public static final String ARTICLE_NO_OF_SHARES = "article_no_of_shares";
        public static final String ARTICLE_NO_OF_CHALLENGES = "article_no_of_challenges";
        public static final String ARTICLE_AUTHOR = "article_author";
        public static final String ARTICLE_LONG_DESCRIPTION = "article_long_desc";
        public static final String ARTICLE_IMAGE_URL = "article_image_url";
        public static final String ARTICLE_SHARE_URL = "article_share_url";


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String mCreateAritcleTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LEARNARTICLES
                    + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ARTICLE_CODE
                    + " TEXT, " + ARTICLE_SHORT_DESC + " TEXT, " + ARTICLE_DATE
                    + " TEXT," + ARTICLE_NO_OF_SHARES + " INTEGER, "
                    + ARTICLE_NO_OF_CHALLENGES + " INTEGER, " + ARTICLE_AUTHOR
                    + " TEXT, " + ARTICLE_LONG_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                    + ARTICLE_IMAGE_URL + " TEXT, " + ARTICLE_SHARE_URL + " TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(mCreateAritcleTable);
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please answer this?

Comment: what are the devices that are crashing? one plus two?

Comment: Nexus 5, Note 2, Note 3, Yu

Comment: @David I do have these kind of crashes on One Plus Two - do you know a solution for this?

Comment: @swalkner unfortunately not. I had to disable the onplusTwo (the only device) from sales in the Play Store.

Comment: @Anu have you got the solution for this.. I'm facing the same issue..

Comment: @Akshay No, I didn't yet find a solution for it.