# SQLite statement aborts, database locked in Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

In my app I am inserting data in my SQLite database using ORMLite. On some devices I get the following error when inserting data:

```
02-05 09:29:56.864  22365-22441/com.app E/SQLiteLog﹕ (5) statement aborts at 2: [PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST]
02-05 09:29:56.864  22365-22441/com.app W/SQLiteConnection﹕ Could not change the database journal mode of '/data/data/com.app/databases/app.db' from 'wal' to 'PERSIST' because the database is locked.  This usually means that there are other open connections to the database which prevents the database from enabling or disabling write-ahead logging mode.  Proceeding without changing the journal mode.
```

I have no idea how I can fix this problem for ORMLite. Does anyone have a fix for my problem? Only accessing one SQLOpenHelper isn't going to solve my problem since I am using ORMLite and don't use the SQLOpenHelper directly from my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Database Locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930139/android-database-locked)

Comment: @AmitVaghela He isn't using ORMLite

Comment: check that solution it will solve your issue @Bart Bergmans

Comment: @AmitVaghela His solution is using only one SQLOpenHelper, I am not using one since I am using ORMLite (which is also a solution from him, use ORMLite)

Comment: you got solution, is good to know @Bart Bergmans

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a solution. I executed the following code from each of my DatabaseManagers:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;", null);
cursor.close();
```

I get a lot less statement aborts errors but I am still getting a few of them. Should I run that code after every query or is this not a good solution?

Comment: how to add this in room?
val db: SupportSQLiteDatabase? = roomDb.openHelper.writableDatabase;
val cursor: Cursor = db!!.query("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;", null);
 cursor.close()
???

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a query before this statement it seems that the executing of that threat is still executing ?

Maybe you need to wait for the result before starting the other query?
Not sure if that is the case trying to think with ya.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, there in an ingoing operation. Maybe some kind of operation is slower in one device that another. Review your code keeping it in mind

Comment: How can I see what operation is running? I waited a while before running a new query and I still get the error. On other devices I don't have this problem.