# Reading data during ORMLite transaction

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I'm currently developing an Android app with ORMLite.

My problem is that i have to do big database transaction in the background while the user wants to read some data from the database. The unacceptable result is that the app does not respond until the transaction is finished.

I have read many about transactions and ORMLite now but I am still not sure how to solve the problem. I think that i want do a "non-exclusive" transaction (or also called "immediate mode").

If this is right, how can i do such an transaction with ORMLite?

Comment: What is your background task ? Maybe it can be optimize to be faster. :)

Comment: The background task is optimized as much as possible. But even if not this can not be the solution. The transaction in the background should never influence the response time of the UI.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't know how you can manage that without manage your background task (like stop it and restart). I +1 your question and wait for an answer from someone better than me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending 2 days reading documentations and blogs I found the answer!

It just one method call on the SQLiteDatabase which does the job:

```
enableWriteAheadLogging()
```

That's it. Now I can read and write simultaneously.

For more information have a look at [SQLite simultaneous reading and writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104832/sqlite-simultaneous-reading-and-writing)