# Android onUpgrade() fails because database is locked, what should I do differently?

Tags: android, database, locked

I have a project with a set of classes that are responsible for their respective database tables.

Each table managing class contains CRUD methods that follow the pattern of get connection, run crud operation, close connection:

```
public class PersonManager {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DbAdapter dbAdapter; //This is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper

    public void addPerson(Person person)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("email", person.email);
        contentValues.put("first_name", person.firstName);

        db = dbAdapter.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert("person", null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    ...other crud/utility methods omitted...
}
```

Now that I am upgrading my database via onUpgrade(), I run into database locked issues.

The exact error message follows:

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked
```

It appears that onUpgrade is either meant to:

```
1 run db.execSQL() calls or
2 use helper classes that use onUpgrade()'s SQLiteDatabase rather than their own
```

It would be much easier to use my table managing classes to migrate data in onUpgrade() than db.execSQL() statements, or rewrite all my CRUD methods to take onUpgrade()'s SQLiteDatabase.

Am I setting up my database access correctly? If the above code follows the correct pattern, what should I do to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I've encountered this issue before. Just a few questions to help narrow it down, are you doing any threading, and is your SQLiteOpenHelper in this instance a singleton? There should only be one access point (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3689883/429047).

Comment: I have a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I instantiate this class rather than return a static instance. I wasn't sure if it was okay to pass a Context reference to a singleton incase that reference went away. I also open and close the connection on each CRUD method.

Comment: What I don't understand is why it fails on that specific table on Upgrade - android_metadata should exist prior to upgrading. Can you post your onUpgrade method from your helper?

Comment: I'm still solidifying what is going on, but it appears that you cannot call getWritableDatabase() from onUpgrade() even if the getWritableDatabase() call is made indirectly via a table manager class. This is a problem because most of the literature points a person to open and close connections when they are used instead of keeping some global connection open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any answers, so I asked on a dev hangout.

According to the Android Developer Hangout Team, onUpgrade is only meant for structure alterations, not really for data migration/manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
db = dbAdapter.getWritableDatabase();
```

When you're in onUpgrade(), you have to use the SQLiteDatabase handle that onUpgrade() provides you.  So your solution is to rewrite your  addPerson function to take one more argument -- an SQLiteDatabase handle:

```
public void addPerson(Person person, SQLiteDatabase db) {...}
```

If you need to call addPerson() from elsewhere in your project, then keep your current addPerson(Person person) function, have it do that
    db = dbAdapter.getWritableDatabase()
call, and pass db to your two-argument version of addPerson().