# Database call crashes Android Application

Tags: android, database, onclicklistener

i am using a Android database and it's set up; but when i call it within an onClickListener the app crashes.

the code i am using is

```
db.open();
mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               s = WorkoutChoice.this.weight.getText().toString();
               s2 = WorkoutChoice.this.height.getText().toString();
               int w = Integer.parseInt(s);
               double h = Double.parseDouble(s2);
               double BMI = (w/h)/h;
               t.setText(""+BMI);
               long id = db.insertTitle("001", ""+days, ""+BMI);
               Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
               if (c.moveToFirst())
               {
                   do {          
                       DisplayTitle(c);
                   } while (c.moveToNext());
               }
            }
        });
        db.close();
```

and the log cat for when i run it is:

```
 04-01 18:21:54.704: E/global(6333): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
04-01 18:21:54.704: E/global(6333): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-01 18:21:54.704: E/global(6333):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
04-01 18:21:54.704: E/global(6333):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1391)
04-01 18:21:54.704: E/global(6333):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1356)
04-01 18:21:54.704: E/global(6333):     at com.b00348312.workout.Splashscreen$1.run(Splashscreen.java:42)
04-01 18:22:09.444: D/dalvikvm(6333): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4221 objects / 252640 bytes in 31ms
04-01 18:22:09.474: I/dalvikvm(6333): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
04-01 18:22:09.574: D/dalvikvm(6333): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1304 objects / 302920 bytes in 29ms
04-01 18:22:09.744: D/dalvikvm(6333): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2480 objects / 290848 bytes in 33ms
04-01 18:22:10.034: D/dalvikvm(6333): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6334 objects / 374152 bytes in 36ms
04-01 18:22:14.344: D/AndroidRuntime(6333): Shutting down VM
04-01 18:22:14.344: W/dalvikvm(6333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1567)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at com.b00348312.workout.DataBaseHelper.insertTitle(DataBaseHelper.java:84)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice$3.onClick(WorkoutChoice.java:84)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-01 18:22:14.364: E/AndroidRuntime(6333):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have noticed errors when the application opens but i don't know where they are from.

When I take out the statements to do with the database there are no errors and everthing runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't help if the database is only open while you set the listener, it has to be open when you use it. Call `open()` and `close()` INSIDE the `onCLick()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't Opened and Closed the Databaase.

Before use of Cursor

```
db.open();
```

and after use of Cursor

```
db.close();
```

Try this thing.

Comment: i do have a db.open(); and db.Close(); before and after. i'll edit the post to indicate that

Comment: @DarrenMurtagh you have but you don't open / close it in the onClick part which is asynchronously called at some point in the future so the db.close already happened.

Comment: @DarrenMurtagh: Just Put it Inside the not outside, Because when you click the Button then only you want to open the Database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the best practices for sqlite in android.

Sqlite can not properly handle multiple connections (thread), even if they are properly synchronized. Use a helper, or a content provider.

[What are the best practices for SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-is-best-practice-with-sqlite-and-android)