# How to over come from Database Locked Exception?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am implementing an app where I make database calls frequently.

I open the database using following code:

```
public DataBaseHelper open() throws SQLException {

      mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
      this.mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this;
 }
```

but I get database locked exception in the following line:

```
 this.mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Please help me fix this exception.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make DataBaseHelper class static? Seems you are creating many connections. Another nice way would be to set some connection pooling mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem arises when you use several connections with your database.
try to avoid creating multiple connections to the database and use the one with all your functions

[Database locked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213436/database-locked-exception)