# Best way to access database in multi threaded application Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

**Note:  Please don't mark this question as a duplicate. I have gone through several similar questions but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.**

I have been working on an application which uses Sqlite Database. We are following singleton pattern which ensures that we can create only one instance of our helper class throughout our application.

```
public class CustomSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static CustomSqliteHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized (CustomSqliteHelper.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new CustomSqliteHelper(context);
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

But  sometimes the application crashes with `SQLiteDatabaseLockedException`. I understand this  exception comes when more than one thread/process tries to write to the database at one time. Even if one thread/process tries to read the database when the write operation is still going on, this exception will be thrown.

So I have been reading a lot about this and the possible ways to prevent this from happening. A lot of posts suggests using ContentProvider instead of directly extending `SqliteOpenHelper` class and performing operations on the database object. While reading one of the posts, this [post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html) mentioned that while using Content Provider, you don’t need to manually take care of the multi threaded environment.

> Although the ContentProvider lacks in thread-safety, often times you will find that no further action is required on your part with respect to preventing potential race conditions. The canonical example is when your ContentProvider is backed by a SQLiteDatabase; when two threads attempt to write to the database at the same time, the SQLiteDatabase will lock itself down, ensuring that one will wait until the other has completed. Each thread will be given mutually exclusive access to the data source, ensuring the thread safety is met.

The above quote seems sounds confusing because first it mentions that ContentProvider does not support thread safety. But he concludes that the application developer doesn't need to do anything on his part to achieve concurrency.

Also, if I choose to use SqliteOpenHelper, what will be the best way to prevent these crashes? I have been thinking of using locks for every db operation.

```
 public class CustomSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private String lock = "lock";

 public void insert(){
    synchronized(lock){
       // Do the insert operation here.
    }
 }


 public void update(){
    synchronized(lock){
       // Do the update operation here.
    }
 }
 }
```

But one of my team members advised me not to do so because Java locks are expensive.

After going through one of the most popular [projects](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper) on Github, I found that the developers have advised to wrap every database operation inside a transaction.

```
public void insert(ContentValues values) {
    // Create and/or open the database for writing
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    // It's a good idea to wrap our insert in a transaction. This helps with performance and ensures
    // consistency of the database.
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        // The user might already exist in the database (i.e. the same user created multiple posts).

        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_POSTS, null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to add post to database");
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

I am really not sure if this can prevent the Lock exception? This seems more like a performance oriented step.

So finally after reading all those blogs and tutorials, I am still confused. My main questions are

1. Which is a better choice to use ContentProviders or extending
   SqliteOpenHelper given that my application doesn't share data with
   other applications.
2. Is putting Java locks on all the operations the
   best approach or is there any other approach which is better than this?

**Update:** Based on the answer by @Mustanar, it seems that the SQLiteDatabase takes care of the locking mechanism. It means that if you are doing a write opertaion, the database will be locked. But at the very same time, if some other thread tries to perform a write operation, then will the second operation be in waiting till the lock is released or will it throw an `android.sqlite.database.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException` exception ?

**Update 2**: Putting a bounty on this question, because the answer still seems to be not clear to me. I am using only one instance of the Helper class. But still getting this error.

**P.S: Thanks for bearing for such a long question.**

Comment: Java locks are less expensive than anything the database does.

Comment: "But sometimes the application crashes with SQLiteDatabaseLockedException" -- in the future, please provide a [mcve], as we cannot help you debug code and a stack trace that does not exist. "if some other thread tries to perform a write operation, then will the second operation be in waiting till the lock is released" -- it should.

Comment: Logs from exception would be also useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Singleton` pattern to instantiate the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so throughout the application one instance of singleton should exist. ***This will ensure that no leaks occur, and will make your life a lot easier since it eliminates the possibility of forgetting to close your database as you code. It also will ensure safe access to the database throughout the application.***

Moreover, You don't have to implement your own locking mecanism. `SQLiteDatabase` maintain the locking mecanism. So, There will only one transaction going at a particular time, all other transactions will be in `Queue` using the `Sigleton.getInstance()` approach. Ensure a single access point to the database.

Moreover, in this approach, ***You don't have to close your database connections, as SQLiteDatabase will be releasing all references once transaction has been done.*** So `CustomSQLiteHelper.getInstance()` should be used whenever you want to perform CRUD operations and remove your locking mecansim.

More information, Please go through the blog http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html and see the comments also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that I am using a singleton pattern, But still I am getting SqliteDatabaseLockedException.

Comment: At which line your are getting this exception? Please post the stacktrace. Have you removed your locking mecanism?

Comment: No, there was no locking mechanism in the first place. After getting the crash, I am thinking to put manual locks. Thats why I posted the question to discuss the appraoch.

Comment: You don't need for manual locking. please post the stacktrace

Comment: stacktrace doesn't make any sense here. It simply states "Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException". Moreover my question is more about discussing the approach. And as you are saying that you don't need manual locking for multi threading applications. I tried to excecute 4 threads concurrently and each thread was inserting 10000 records in a single table. At that time I was able to get this exception. Clearly the sqlite doesn't take care of concurrency. And yeah I was using singleton pattern.

Comment: As long as you are doing the CRUD operations through single point of contact, you dont need concurrency because sqlite do that. Can you please make sure that from different threads, you are executing operations through `CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance()` instead of direct accessing the `SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: yeah definitely, everytime we are doing CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance().getWritableDatabase() for getting the database instance.

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct. The SQliteDatabase takes care of locking mechanism. It means when I do one write operation, the db is locked. But if at the same time another thread tries to do a  write operation, will the db wait till the second lock is released or will it throw an exception ?

Comment: You don't have to getWritableDatabase from outside the SQLiteOpenHelper class. You should do operations in SQLiteHelper. Secondly, DB will waite for first operation to complete

Comment: Accepting this answer, because after a lot of search on the internet, I came upon the conclusion that SqLite itself takes care of the locking mechanism and if one uses singleton pattern, then this exception will not occur which was what suggested in the answer.

Comment: I'm using a singleton pattern, but still getting `SQLiteDatabaseLockedException` exception occasionally...

Answer (score 1):

**Query 1 (Singleton) :**

**Can you change below double locking code to create a true Singleton object?**

```
public class CustomSqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      private CustomSqliteHelper instance;
      public static CustomSqliteHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
          synchronized (CustomSqliteHelper.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
              instance = new CustomSqliteHelper(context);
            }
          }
        }
        return instance;
      }
    }
```

Have a look at this [article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html) to understand the issues with double locking.

Have a look at related SE question:

[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

I prefer to create Singleton

```
 private static final CustomSqliteHelper instance = new CustomSqliteHelper ();
```

Other approach:

```
enum CustomSqliteHelper {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

One more approach if you still need lazy Singleton.

Have a look at @ `Nathan Hughes` answer in this SE question:

[Synchronized and locks in singleton factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707141/synchronized-and-locks-in-singleton-factory/)

**Query 2: ( Locking)**

Using java lock is not a bad idea to improve the consistency of the application. Consistency wins over expense.

From [SQLiteDatabaseLockedException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabaseLockedException.html) page,

> Thrown if the database engine was unable to acquire the database locks it needs to do its job. If the statement is a [COMMIT] or occurs outside of an explicit transaction, then you can retry the statement. If the statement is not a [COMMIT] and occurs within a explicit transaction then you should rollback the transaction before continuing.

I hope you should follow above recommendation along with code snippet you have posted in your question (Github) project. I like that idea and above recommendation is in-line with Github example code.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend that you wrap your database in a `ContentProvider`.

It provides nice features out of the box and shifts a lot of potentially tricky tasks to the framework. You won't need to deal with singleton database helpers, because you are guaranteed that you have a single `ContentResolver` instance for your app that will forward commands to the intended provider.

You can make use of the whole `Loader` framework and nice helper classes like `AsyncQueryHandler` to deal with some of the most common caveats of DB access.

I would advice against synchronising the access to your CRUD methods. As mentioned in the documentation and the previous answers, this should be taken care of by the database itself. Not to mention the potential performance penalty in an app that requires intensive database usage.

Side note: As a first step, it may be useful if you try and pinpoint what causes these crashes - are they sporadic? A more concrete example may prove useful while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Content Providers.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a **read-write lock** is enough in most cases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11214125/1174054). The solution does not use `ContentProvider`. Instead, it uses `ReentrantReadWriteLock` class in `java.util.concurrent.locks` package.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Which is a better choice to use ContentProviders or extending SqliteOpenHelper given that my application doesn't share data with other applications.

I'd say extending `SqliteOpenHelper` is much better choice if you are not sharing any data. This is mainly due to it's more dev-friendly API than `ContentProvider` :-) And there is other thing described in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html):

> Decide if you need a content provider. You need to build a content provider if you want to provide one or more of the following features:
>
> - You want to offer complex data or files to other applications.
> - You want to allow users to copy complex data from your app into other apps.
> - You want to provide custom search suggestions using the search framework.

So in your case - it is rather redundant

---

For singleton initializing - sometimes you don't need it to be lazy initialized:

```
public class CustomSqliteHelper {
    private static final CustomSqliteHelper instance = new CustomSqliteHelper(YourApplication.getContext());

    public static CustomSqliteHelper getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    // all the super staff below :)
}
```

But you need to expose app context with your application class:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    private static final YourApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

plus configuration in Manifest. This way you avoid synchronization during creation.

---

If you really need this singleton to be lazy initialized - than I will say that ***double check locking*** (DCL) is very bad practice. For safe lazy initialization you should use the following pattern:

```
public class CustomSqliteHelper {
    private static class InstanceHolder {
        public static CustomSqliteHelper instance = new CustomSqliteHelper(YourApplication.getContext());
    }

    public CustomSqliteHelper getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.instance;
    }

    // all the super staff below :)
}
```

---

> 2. Is putting Java locks on all the operations the best approach or is there any other approach which is better than this?
>      This provides safe lazy initialization without locking anything.

There is no need to do any locking (till your DAO is stateless). Check documentation for [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure SQLiteOpenHelper is a singleton, you need to enable write-ahead logging if you want multiple threads to access the database:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()

Doing this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

As discussed on comments, there will be no Blocking Lock if you use one DB instance. 
So I am doubting DeadLock cause you are using transaction.

a kind of DeadLock example is :

1. in one transaction :

   update A table --> update B table -->commit
2. in other transaction :

   update B table --> update A table -->commit

so in the middle time, 1 waits 2 and 2 waits 1 at the same time, so Deadlock happens.

If it is really Deadlock, you can fix query to not to make this happen
or you can use Queued query(or async query) like Actor.

for example, The commons-dbutils library has support for an AsyncQueryRunner which you provide an ExecutorService to and it returns a Future.
(from: [Is asynchronous jdbc call possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087696/is-asynchronous-jdbc-call-possible))

Comment: How different..  You mean there is no deadlock in SQLite?

Answer (score -2):

To prevent locking errors, set a [busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) of twenty seconds or so in *every* connection. Then you will get an exception only if your app hangs runs a transaction longer than that.

You could also use a single `SQLiteDatabase` object from all threads, but then you would have to lock it manually around all transactions.