# Database and multithreading Issue android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm making an app where I need to have 2 threads accessing the database at the same time. As an ideal practice I'm using a singleton class for handling database. However, I've read at [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android/3689883#3689883) places that even in singleton classes if two threads try to write simultaneously , one of them will fail. How should I solve this issue or is there a better approach to this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried a synchronized lock ?

Comment: "as an ideal practice i'm using a singleton..." <= this is not ideal ... ideal is ContentProvider ... i'm assuming that you're using [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) ... in documentation is written "This class makes it easy for ContentProvider implementations..." ... anyway ContentProvider is android natural way of data operation

Comment: @Singularity : I've read that even in synchronized lock if 2 threads are trying to write simultaneously one of the request would be rejected. Thats why I haven't tried it yet. Is it true ?

Comment: @GauravTheNewGeek `synchronized` lock makes threads trying to get it **wait until its free**.

Comment: @Singularity: Okey, would the final solution would be making all methods `synchronized` and accessing database via a single instance for all threads? Will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does that for you, other threads wait for current one to insert/update, and there is a method [`isDbLockedByCurrentThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isDbLockedByCurrentThread%28%29) to know if you got a lock on DB. Still I'd recommend using a sync-lock to be sure and avoid other deadlocks and race conditions. Create a special gateway class that defines all update/insert methods at one place, make those methods `synchronized`.

Comment: My app still crashes probably because I'm using multiple SQLiteOpenHelper subclasses for different tables and hence, multiple instances of SQLiteDatabase. How should I go about this issue? Thanks !

Comment: @GauravTheNewGeek Don't, one database can have as many tables you want.