# What are the best practices for updating sqlite data?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

My application does not use internet, though I am using php(json) to get certain data from a local mysql database and parse the JSONObject to Java and **save** it to sqlite in Android.

I am using this to dynamically populate my android menus from the mysql data(local database). I think this call for a better practice when it comes in getting updates in the database. I will be deleting the previous menu in my sqlite and fetch another data from mysql.

Comment: can you post some code and your table structure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did since I want to update my sqlite database, I incremeted my database version if there are new updated. Also I put an indicator from my outside database so that my app can check if there are available updates.