# What is difference Between google analytics v3 and google analytics v4 ? android

Tags: android

I am using Google Analytics v4 in Android application but i want to know:
What is difference between Google Analytics v3 and Google Analytics v4 ?

Comment: refer [GA for v4](http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api) and [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v2/migration-guide)

Comment: which is Best v4 or v3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the v4 Google Analytics API has a number of helper classes and configuration options which can make getting up and running fairly straight forwards.

YOu can get more info [here](http://benwilcock.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android/)

Comment: which is Best v4 or v3 ?

Comment: Rohit bro..Please tell me the best way of handle my DataBase .with fast insertion and updation.

Comment: @DeepakRor: Follow this link it will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android

Comment: V4 absolutely DOES require Google Play services. This is very clear from the documentation and the gradle call to include it:     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'