# SQlite operations completes half if user remove the application

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

As suggested by developers, The sqlite operations must be performed on the Background thread. But in some cases, if the sqlite operations are being performed on Background thread And during that, the user remove the application from recent task.

```
This causes app to be gone in an undesired state. Sometimes cause a crash next time when I open my app.
```

If I perform sqlite operation on UI thread, everything goes fine.
My app has lot of sqlite operations to  be performed at lot of times. How should I deal with this.

Comment: consider creating a service for that task

Comment: an asynctask can help you

Comment: @SMR But as I remove my application, The service restarts, causing that task to be left uncompleted.

Comment: is removing=unistall or something else?

Comment: @SMR removing means here, I press the "Home" button and remove the app from recent task.

Comment: service dont necessarily restart see [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). There are various types of services and their configuration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android this may be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks @SMR. Except Foreground service. How can I start a service that doesn't automatically restarts itself when I remove the app from recent task.