# Inserting to Database from 2 separate AsyncTasks

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am trying to insert into my database from 2 `AsyncTask`s.

I have only one static instance of my `SQLiteDatabase` object, both `AsyncTask`s are executed with a `SerialExecutor`, when I am starting both DB transactions I am passing in a `SQLiteTransactionListener` and the `onCommit` callback is called for both inserts (I have tried using `beginTransactionWithListenerNonExclusive()` and `beginTransactionWithListener()`), and still the second insert fails to write into my db (no exceptions nothing indicating that it has failed).

Basically, I have an `AsyncTaskLoader` and in its `onLoadFinished`, I read my JSON and after that I fire the first `AsyncTask` where I start inserting into my DB, as this goes along there is a button that fetches me a list and populates a `ListView` of data from the same table where the first `asyncTask` writes into.

When I click on any of the items from the `ListView`, I fetch the data relevant for this selected item and insert a new entry in the same table (all of that fetching and inserting happens in a second `AsyncTask`).

The `onCommit` callback for the second `asyncTask` insert is called and when the second `asyncTask` finishes (`onPostExecuted` is called), I start a new activity where I am supposed to read the newly inserted data (interesting enough, that failing to insert happens randomly).

Even though both of my `AsyncTask`s are executed in serial (meaning the second one should wait for the first one to finish, right?) and the `Listener` tells me that the data is inserted, only the first `AsyncTask` successfully inserts the data. Why is this occurring?

Comment: because only the first was executed check this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M

Comment: I am using executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SerialExecutor) for both with the idea that they won't insert at the same time in the DB. From what I understand if u try to insert into the db from 2 threads simontaneously it won't work ?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android/3689883#3689883