# Android: get info from database and populate listview in background. What to use?

Tags: android

I have an Android app with SQL Lite database. I want to access it in background thread to populate `listView`.

What should I use: `AsycnTask`, `Thread` or `Service`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for SQLite on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Best combination would be, ListFragment, Sqlite (with or without content provider), CursorLoader, CursorAdapter, Service.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time I prefer to use **[Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)** here are some sample Example **[Loader and LoaderManager with Cursor](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/60331340133/very-simple-example-of-a-loader-and-loadermanager)** and tutorial **[Android Design Patterns : Why Loaders](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html).**

Loader characteristics

> 1. They are available to every Activity and Fragment.
> 2. They provide asynchronous loading of data.
> 3. They monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the content changes.
> 4. They automatically reconnect to the last loader's cursor when being recreated after a configuration change. Thus, they don't need to re-query their data.