# Android: Will several SQLLite databases, one for each table, speed up concurrent writes?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

It has been observed before, that concurrently writing to a SQLLite database is "slow" if we don't use transactions ([see  this](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) ... not sure how this applies to Android where we write to an SD card though). And this was reported without several threads writing to the same database. I remember reading that in case of using multiple threads to write to the database locking slows things down even more (I will add the article if I find it again).

Now, I have a scenario where I write from fourteen threads to a single database. Each write starts at about the same time every second and consists of 1 to 60 entries. **Each thread writes to a different table. Those tables are completely independent**, i.e., I will never have to do a join or anything the like. Which makes mz scenario quite different from those, e.g., in [What are the best practices for SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android/3689883#3689883)

My question is, while I have already optimized by caching entries and writing them to the database using transactions, I am still wondering if I could further speed up things by creating a **separate database for each table**. That is, threads should not be locking this way. But I am not sure if this would have the desired effect, i.e., **getting rid of locking altogether**.

Does any of you have experience with this or can explain to me why or why not my approach would be a good idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider that your DB is on a phone, which uses flash memory. using different files means re-writing entirely different blocks of that flash, meaning performance may actually suffer MORE from using multiple files, rather than a single file where the writes to each of those tables can be combined into a write of a single flash block.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was thinking along the same lines, but the locking mechanism of SQLLite would prevent writes from different threads to be combined, I think, because for each write it locks until the file system confirms the update. At least that is how I understood it from the SQLLite FAQ linked above. What do you think?

Comment: @MarcB The flash already does wear leveling, so all new data will end up in the same block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did some **experiments** in my scenario. The **results are not really clear, but overall I would say, that either approach should be OK (using one or using separate databases)**. *What I noticed is that, there is a slight trend towards separate databases for each table being slower initially but speeding up over time, while using a single database seems to be faster at the beginning but slows slightly over time*. In this post, I will report my findings and accept it as an answer for now. If anybody has a more thorough explanation, possibly with some theory instead of just empirical evidence, I would change the accept.

Scenario in detail: I am working with the Microsoft Band 2 Android API, and for each sensor I am defining a listener using a HandlerThread and subscribe it to the sensor manager (always using max. frequency). Each listener gets a SQLiteOpenHelper which it uses to get a writable database "getWriteableDatabase". The fast sensors I cache 60 samples before writing to the database. **Now, we can either define a different SQLiteOpenHelper for each sensor or use the same one**.

Since we agree that using transitions makes things a lot faster (I was able to confirm speedups of a factor 20), I use transactions throughout the following experiments, that is for the sensors where I cache 60 samples before writing to the database.

## Experiments

In the experiments I calculate the average over several insert for each sensor/thread. I report the time and the number of samples used for averaging. The format is

```
([average insert time in ms] / [number of runs] / [last insert time in ms]  ): [SENSOR]: [number of inserted values]
```

### A single SQLiteOpenHelper for all threads (one database)

#### Run 1

```
(93.18840579710145 / 69.0 / 76 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(99.52307692307693 / 65.0 / 66 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(35.323076923076925 / 130.0 / 134 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(41.0735294117647 / 68.0 / 148 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(37.257234726688104 / 311.0 / 114 ): GSR: 1
(43.79032258064516 / 62.0 / 57 ): CALORIES: 1
(41.62903225806452 / 62.0 / 41 ): DISTANCE: 1
(49.233333333333334 / 60.0 / 50 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(43.896907216494846 / 97.0 / 47 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(35.76923076923077 / 65.0 / 12 ): BAROMETER: 1
(44.223880597014926 / 67.0 / 22 ): ALTIMETER: 1
...
(105.2179675994109 / 679.0 / 62 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(106.58554572271386 / 678.0 / 68 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(41.799546142208776 / 1322.0 / 33 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(48.519578313253014 / 664.0 / 35 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(36.98158768487775 / 3313.0 / 67 ): GSR: 1
(46.8031007751938 / 645.0 / 18 ): CALORIES: 1
(46.826219512195124 / 656.0 / 14 ): DISTANCE: 1
(56.807633587786256 / 655.0 / 18 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(45.56761729530819 / 1087.0 / 18 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(49.16944024205749 / 661.0 / 31 ): BAROMETER: 1
(60.404833836858 / 662.0 / 40 ): ALTIMETER: 1
```

#### Run 2

```
(88.95454545454545 / 66.0 / 128 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(75.109375 / 64.0 / 66 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(31.906976744186046 / 129.0 / 16 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(25.863636363636363 / 66.0 / 15 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(27.237942122186496 / 311.0 / 15 ): GSR: 1
(33.08064516129032 / 62.0 / 8 ): CALORIES: 1
(29.258064516129032 / 62.0 / 10 ): DISTANCE: 1
(39.0655737704918 / 61.0 / 15 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(32.406976744186046 / 86.0 / 11 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(32.640625 / 64.0 / 82 ): BAROMETER: 1
(41.292307692307695 / 65.0 / 89 ): ALTIMETER: 1
...
(94.10264385692068 / 643.0 / 61 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(77.9188767550702 / 641.0 / 77 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(33.86671987230646 / 1253.0 / 19 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(30.63809523809524 / 630.0 / 33 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(28.691152986266367 / 3131.0 / 12 ): GSR: 1
(32.55810147299509 / 611.0 / 22 ): CALORIES: 1
(31.56774193548387 / 620.0 / 41 ): DISTANCE: 1
(40.27786752827141 / 619.0 / 49 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(31.76108870967742 / 992.0 / 38 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(31.466453674121407 / 626.0 / 11 ): BAROMETER: 1
(40.610845295055825 / 627.0 / 19 ): ALTIMETER: 1
```

### A different SQLiteOpenHelpers for each thread (one database for each sensor)

#### Run 1

```
(201.98076923076923 / 52.0 / 188 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(203.69230769230768 / 52.0 / 72 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(100.16666666666667 / 102.0 / 37 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(125.3    2692307692308 / 52.0 / 47 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(74.4563492063492 / 252.0 / 46 ): GSR: 1
(122.25490196078431 / 51.0 / 13 ): CALORIES: 1
(118.3921568627451 / 51.0 / 34 ): DISTANCE: 1
(127.82352941176471 / 51.0 / 29 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(112.72527472527473 / 91.0 / 34 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(106.27450980392157 / 51.0 / 18 ): BAROMETER: 1
(128.2941176470588 / 51.0 / 24 ): ALTIMETER: 1
...
(103.7621776504298 / 698.0 / 71 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(99.96418338108883 / 698.0 / 102 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(27.61911764705882 / 1360.0 / 20 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(31.57247437774524 / 683.0 / 37 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(24.713699031974187 / 3409.0 / 13 ): GSR: 1
(31.17921686746988 / 664.0 / 28 ): CALORIES: 1
(34.1037037037037 / 675.0 / 26 ): DISTANCE: 1
(36.275555555555556 / 675.0 / 31 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(30.485689505637467 / 1153.0 / 26 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(32.23494860499266 / 681.0 / 10 ): BAROMETER: 1
(36.75917767988253 / 681.0 / 16 ): ALTIMETER: 1
```

#### Run 2

```
(126.11940298507463 / 67.0 / 77 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(128.82539682539684 / 63.0 / 44 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(58.16153846153846 / 130.0 / 29 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(62.53731343283582 / 67.0 / 28 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(50.798701298701296 / 308.0 / 9 ): GSR: 1
(81.62903225806451 / 62.0 / 33 ): CALORIES: 1
(57.45161290322581 / 62.0 / 19 ): DISTANCE: 1
(60.56666666666667 / 60.0 / 14 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(61.56603773584906 / 106.0 / 14 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(68.078125 / 64.0 / 23 ): BAROMETER: 1
(80.27272727272727 / 66.0 / 27 ): ALTIMETER: 1
...
(78.23076923076923 / 702.0 / 105 ): ACCELEROMETER: 60
(82.7560975609756 / 697.0 / 56 ): GYROSCOPE: 60
(27.407326007326006 / 1365.0 / 16 ): AMBIENT_LIGHT: 1
(25.03202328966521 / 687.0 / 17 ): HEART_RATE: 1
(22.503373423291286 / 3409.0 / 20 ): GSR: 1
(27.905263157894737 / 665.0 / 10 ): CALORIES: 1
(28.832592592592594 / 675.0 / 13 ): DISTANCE: 1
(30.034175334323923 / 673.0 / 17 ): PEDOMETER: 1
(25.60211267605634 / 1136.0 / 22 ): RR_INTERVAL: 1
(29.501466275659823 / 682.0 / 18 ): BAROMETER: 1
(33.88157894736842 / 684.0 / 23 ): ALTIMETER: 1
```