# How to retrieve a single data from a particular column using row id from sqlite table in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

There are several columns in a sqlite table. I want to retrieve a particular data using row id. For example : I want the data of the column "name" which have row id "1". How can I do this in android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best practices for SQLite on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

An example of my code:

```
private static String t(String i, String table) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = ODB.getInstance().openDatabase();
        String lng = hl;
        String Sid = "Sid___";
        String sql = "SELECT " + lng + "  FROM " + table  + " WHERE " + Sid + " = '" +  i + "'";
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        String out = "";
         if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                 out =(cur.getString(0);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
              }else{
                  throw new NullPointerException();
              }
         cur.close();
         ODB.getInstance().closeDatabase();
         return out;
    }
```