# Using firebase database how to filter time?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, time, filtering

I have a problem to filter time in the **firebase database**, I wanted to write a program which always filter data from ten minutes ago to now in the firebase using Android Java but i didn t do it.
I tried to write with `startat()` but as i said it didn t work.

```
`Query query=database.getReference("handler").child("button").orderByChild("time").startAt(start).endAt(finish);query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){HashMap hashmap = (HashMap) ds.getValue();list.add(hashmap.get("realtime"));
textView.setText(list.size());}}} `

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @israfilll please add some of your code to your question

Comment: actually i am trying to get data from database which is in the last 10 minutes when i send data to firebase database but it must be continous

Comment: @israfilll, as for me, I am not aware what the issue is, you have to show us some more code on Android side and some more information how you are trying to access it, meanwhile have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android