# How to show a value from SQLite in a textView?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to get a value from SQLite to show it in a textView called "tvPackMoney".

```
        String packMoney = Float.toString(daoHelperPacks.sendPackStats().getPackMoney());
        tvPackMoney.setText(packMoney);
```

The method to find the value in the database is this:

```
public ObjectPack sendPackStats (){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String currentPlayer = ClassSharedPreferences.read(ClassSharedPreferences.currentPlayer, "");//read string in shared preference.
        String currentPack = ClassSharedPreferences.read(ClassSharedPreferences.currentPack, "");//read string in shared preference.

        Cursor datos = db.rawQuery("SELECT MONEY_PACK FROM "+MI_TABLA+" WHERE PLAYER_PACK ='"+currentPlayer+"' AND NAME_PACK ='"+currentPack+"' FROM "+MI_TABLA+")",null);

        ObjectPack objectPack = new ObjectPack();

        if (datos.moveToFirst()){
            objectPack.setPackMoney(datos.getFloat(0));
        }
        db.close();
        return objectPack;
    }
```

I used debugger and I get force close when the following line is executed:

```
String packMoney = Float.toString(daoHelperPacks.sendPackStats().getPackMoney());
```

But writing a value directly there is no problem, everything works.

```
String packMoney = Float.toString((float) 1.11);
```

Someone can see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here the logcat:

```
W/actual.pregres: Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->isMainThread()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->isMainThread()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession;->hasTransaction()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/ContentValues;->isEmpty()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession;->hasConnection()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->isInMemoryDatabase()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabaseConfiguration;->isInMemoryDb()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->isReadOnlyLocked()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/actual.pregres: Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->dispose(Z)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->onCorruption()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->getLabel()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->DEBUG_ONEPLUS:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mCursorFactory:Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/actual.pregres: Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession;->setTransactionSuccessful()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/ContentValues;->isEmpty()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->getThreadDefaultConnectionFlags(Z)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->yieldIfContendedHelper(ZJ)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
I/chatty: uid=10443(com.doctoractual.pregresp) ection primary] identical 1 line
W/actual.pregres: Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->yieldIfContendedHelper(ZJ)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
D/ViewRootImpl[ManagerActivity]: windowFocusChanged hasFocus=false inTouchMode=true
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@8b9e305
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.doctoractual.pregresp, PID: 30713
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doctoractual.pregresp/com.doctoractual.pregresp.SuccessErrorGameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.doctoractual.pregresp.ObjectPack com.doctoractual.pregresp.DAOHelperPacks.sendPackStats()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3375)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3514)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.doctoractual.pregresp.ObjectPack com.doctoractual.pregresp.DAOHelperPacks.sendPackStats()' on a null object reference
        at com.doctoractual.pregresp.SuccessErrorGameActivity.onCreate(SuccessErrorGameActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7804)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3514) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2110) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30713 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:56772', transport: 'socket'
```

Edited:
**SOLUTION**

The query had a mistake

**WRONG QUERY**

```
Cursor datos = db.rawQuery("SELECT MONEY_PACK FROM "+MI_TABLA+" WHERE PLAYER_PACK ='"+currentPlayer+"' AND NAME_PACK ='"+currentPack+"' FROM "+MI_TABLA+")",null);
```

**CORRECT QUERY**

```
Cursor datos = db.rawQuery("SELECT MONEY_PACK FROM "+MI_TABLA+" WHERE PLAYER_PACK='"+currentPlayer+"' AND NAME_PACK='"+currentPack+"'",null);
```

Comment: From the exception it appears your object, daoHelperPacks, is null, did you check to see it's value?

Comment: Also the syntax from "Cursor datos" is wrong

Comment: @DanBaruch Thanks for your answer. It helped me to find my mistake. I appreciate it.

Comment: @javdromero Thanks for your help. You were right, that was the mistake. I didn´t have to add "from MI_TABLA" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteDatabase queries can be a heavy duty especially if the table is large.

I would start threading stuff if you have a lot of operations going on, like a bunch of queries, or complicated queries that span several tables.

sometimes even if the table isn't that big, on some devices it can cause your application to lag. so I recommend doing this in a separate thread preferably using a Loader to avoid handling all the stuff related to your activity's life cycle.

you can get more help from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493331/what-are-the-best-practices-for-sqlite-on-android)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Very useful. You were right. The problem was wrong query to SQLite. It helped me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the issue is that you are calling `this.getWritableDatabase()` method in your `sendPackStats()` method. **It should be `this.getReadableDatabase()`**. If it does not fix the problem

1. Your query could be wrong in terms of syntax.
2. Test to see if your `sendPackStatus()` is returning any value.
3. If you are calling your `sendPackStatus()` asynchronously, make sure you are not setting the text, before you have any value in `String packMoney`. Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Very useful, showing different options to try. Number 1 was the key. Wrong syntax in that query.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Cheers!